# Graphics error with NSStatusItem

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

My application uses NSStatusItem to be visible to the user. 
So I set 'Application is agent (UIElement)' to YES, which basically hides the menu bar of the application, and hides the icon from the dock.
Now, I didn't delete the menu bar, so I can still react to shortcuts like cmd+W to close the preference window, or cmd+q to quit the application. The problem is, that anytime I use such a command, the menubar get's messed up. 
I've noticed that other Apps which run in the background, like Growl 2, have the same issue.

[image: Menubar graphics error]

I have no idea how to fix this. 
Hopefully someone of you can help me

I'm running Mountain Lion.

thanks!

**HINT**

It probably has something to do with the 10.8 SKD. I have never noticed this issue before in any application.

Comment: What?  NSToolbarItem?  Did you mean NSStatusItem?

Comment: Please edit the title as well.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `NSMenu`? I presume that the shortcuts won't work, but does the visual bug disappear? Can you use a different object in the responder chain to handle the shortcuts?

Comment: Yes, the bug does not occur, but I don't want to be having to handle the shortcuts in every window/view.

Answer (score 1):

How about move the whole Window menu to be Application menu submenu and then hide it?
You will still receive shortcuts and the highlited menu will be the application menu that is by anyway there (i suppose so, how else you will open preferences window? also shortcut?).

Comment: The menu bar already is hidden. I removed the Preferences option. You open it in the panel.

Comment: I'v tried to set UIElement to YES and can't reproduce your issue... Shortcuts are working just as expected and menu bar is not messed up...

Comment: p.s. maybe it's relevant, i've tried on 10.6.8 and 10.7, my target sdk is 10.6 and deployment target is 10.5.

Comment: my deployment target is 10.6.6, Growls is 10.7. The SDK is 10.8

Comment: Yes, it definitely has something to do with 10.8. I have never noticed this issue before.

Comment: Added a hint to the question.